# Как запарсить инвентарь стим?

Tags: node.js, парсер, puppeteer

В общем, я хочу сделать так, чтобы парсер просматривал инвентарь и выводил те предметы, которые задам ему.

Решил я сделать это с помощью node js и puppeteer, в какой-то момент столкнулся с тем, что я не понимаю как извлечь описание предмета, http://prntscr.com/123tqs6 здесь видно, что в элементах, с классом ItemHolder отвечающих за предметы инвентаря не хранится их название и описание, само описание можно извлечь только после клика на ячейку инвентаря, тогда эти данные появляются в классе item_desc_description. http://prntscr.com/123u3bb.

И, собственно, сам вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы алгоритм кликал на каждый из предметов и извлекал нужную информацию?

Я пока что придумал только такую достаточно непрактичную реализацию: сделать так, чтобы из всех элементов с классом ItemHolder извлекались ссылки и записывались в массив(это я уже сделал) и потом перебирать массив, переходить по каждой ссылке, извлекать информацию, закрывать вкладку с ссылкой, и так пока не переберу все элементы.(это я пока что сделать не смог).

Сама реализация массива с ссылками на все предметы.

```
let html = await page.evaluate(async () => {
        let res = []
        let container = await document.querySelectorAll('div.itemHolder')
        console.log(container);
            
        container.forEach(function(item){
                let skinlink = item.querySelector('a.inventory_item_link').href;

                res.push({
                    skinlink
                 })
```